# How to turn thumbnail data fetched from Youtube into real displaying thumbnails RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube-api

so I've been playing around with the youtube_it gem. The problem is that when I want to display thumbnails it comes out with weird codes like @height445 @width etc. I was wondering what can I do to make the actual pictures display in the table?

Thanks all!

This is the code that it displays when viewing the page.

```
<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3feb470 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/X_C_9xZYWNw/mqdefault.jpg", @height=180, @width=320, @time=nil, @name="mqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3feb020 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/X_C_9xZYWNw/hqdefault.jpg", @height=360, @width=480, @time=nil, @name="hqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fea9a8 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/X_C_9xZYWNw/1.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:01:00.250", @name="start">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fea5b8 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/X_C_9xZYWNw/2.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:02:00.500", @name="middle">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fea288 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/X_C_9xZYWNw/3.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:03:00.750", @name="end">]
```

Comment: Please show the relevant lines of code you have so far (edit the question and use the code formatting - just indent by 4 spaces if not sure). It will be easier to spot where you have got to and what you need to know.

Comment: Added the view's display thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 'weird codes' are just graphical representations of ruby objects. It looks like what you have there is an array of thumbnail objects, so if you want to display them as html images you need to do something like this (this code goes in your `.erb` file):

```
<% @thumbnails.each do |thumbnail| %>
    <%= image_tag(thumbnail.url) %>
<% end %>
```

That will just render the image tags one after the other, which probably isn't what you want, but it should give you the idea.